# Problem displaying correct format from a python csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to display, using the dataframe file, the total duration for each month and the total duration for a particular type of network (mobile) for each month.

data.csv file:

```
index,date,duration,item,month,network,network_type
0,15/10/14 06:58,34.429,data,2014-11,data,data
1,15/10/14 06:58,13,call,2014-11,Vodafone,mobile
```

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df.groupby(['month', 'item']).agg({'duration':sum,'network_type': "count", 'date': 'first'}))
```

Comment: What is the issue in that?

Comment: It's not displaying as asked, i wan to display the total duration for a particular type of network (mobile) for each month. Now, it is only displaying the count of netwroks

Comment: You could try `group by network_type` in place of `item`.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is.

Comment: Please provide the desired output dataframe